# i've wrote the css wrong but i don't know what's wrong

Tags: html, css

i'm working on doing a website and i can't seem to make my css apply and everything appears as plaintext to the side. i've been searching for over an hour, i can't figure out what i've done wrong.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SOLAR RECORDS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width.intial-scale=1.0"
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jura" rel='stylesheet'>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet">

<style type="text/css">

body {
background-color: #0c0c0c;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.sidenav {
height: 100%
width: 0;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: #111
overflow-x: hidden;
padding-top: 60px;
transition: 0.5s;
```

[here's the full text](https://pastebin.com/JLsPVnKz)

Comment: a lot of errors !! meta not closed, missing } and ; .. etc

Answer (score 0):

You've missed the closing `}` in `.sidenav`. Because of this, all of the styles that come after this do not get applied. Adding this in correctly applies the styles that follow it.

In addition to this, you've also missed the closing `>` in your `<meta name>`, meaning your Google Font is not getting applied either.

Finally, your colours all have five characters. You either need to use 3 letters (shorthand) or 6 characters for the full hex value.

You can avoid these mistakes by validating your code with the **[W3 Markup Validation Service.](https://validator.w3.org)**

Here's a working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>SOLAR RECORDS</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width.intial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jura" rel='stylesheet'>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet">

  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background-color: #0c0c0c;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .sidenav {
      height: 100% width: 0;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #111 overflow-x: hidden;
      padding-top: 60px;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .sidenav a {
      padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 25px;
      font-family: 'Opens Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
      color: #ffffff;
      display: block;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .sidenav a:hover {
      color: #cccccc;
    }
    
    .sidenav .closebtn {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 25px;
      font-size: 36px;
      margin-left: 50px;
    }
    
    img.center {
      display: block;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    h1 {
      font-size: 25px;
      font-family: 'Jura', sans-serif;
      color: #ffffff;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <h1>SOLAR RECORDS&trade;</h1>
  <div style="text align: center"><img src="the.png" alt="Records"></div>

  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="/">HOME</a>
    <a href="releases.html">RELEASES</a>
    <a href="artists.html">ARTISTS</a>
    <a href="events.html">EVENTS</a>
    <a href="mixes.html">MIXES</a>
    <a href="news.html">NEWS</a>
    <a href="label.html">LABEL</a>
    <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
  </div>

  <span onclick="openNav()">OPEN</span>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ^ Caught the other one too :)

Comment: and also some `;` missing ;) .. to be honest this deserve to be closed rather than be answered

Comment: ^ No missing semicolons that I can see; hopefully everything should be correct now :P

Comment: there is two missing in the .sidenav rule